# I want to inserted new row in database using linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq-to-sql, insert

I tried to add new items in items table in database using linq to sql like this :

```
Items new_item = new Items();
            new_item.Title = editproductid.Text;
            new_item.Path = @"~\images\" + uploadimage.FileName;
            StaticVa.new_data_context.Items.InsertOnSubmit(new_item);
            StaticVa.new_data_context.SubmitChanges();
```

but I got an exception

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Items' when
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

how can I open it ? or are there another ways to insert ?

Comment: what is the primary key of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the "Auto Generate Value" property in your model for the identity column is set to True, so that Linq to Sql knows to not try to insert a value itself.